# Convert String to Date in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to convert a string into a date in t-sql. However get results that I can't explain.

```
DECLARE @String as char(11)
DECLARE @TString as char(11)

SELECT @String = SUBSTRING([Flat File Source Error Output Column],1,CHARINDEX(',',[Flat File Source Error Output Column])-6)
FROM [ERROR].[Import_V2X]

SELECT @TString = '12/18/2009'

-- Check content before conversion
SELECT @TString as 'CheckTString'
SELECT @String as 'CheckString'

-- Convert the strings to date       
SELECT CONVERT(date,@TString,101) as 'ConvertSuccess'

SELECT CONVERT(date,@String,101) as 'ConvertFails'
```

[Flat File Source Error Output Column] is defined as text in the table

This gives me the following result:

```
CheckTString
------------
12/18/2009 

(1 row(s) affected)

CheckString
-----------

12/18/2009

(1 row(s) affected)

ConvertSuccess
--------------
2009-12-18

(1 row(s) affected)

ConvertFails
------------
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Anybody can explain me where the problem is or comes from ? 
For me the strings look exactly the same :(

Comment: Since you're variables are 11 characters long and a date formatted this way is only 10 characters, perhaps that 11th character is a nonprintable character that's throwing it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of your output you have a line feed in the checkstring variable.  If this is not just a copy and paste error in the question, that will cause the error that you are describing.  See below

```
DECLARE @TString as char(11)


SELECT @TString = '
12/18/2009'

-- Check content before conversion
SELECT @TString as 'CheckTString'

-- Convert the strings to date       
SELECT CONVERT(date,@TString,101) as 'ConvertFails'
```

Gives the following results.

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: Hi everybody, indeed there was something at the beginning of the string. I had tried LTRIM and RTRIM and assumed that there was nothing (and looking at the output I couldn't see anything as well, until now). But now I tried:

SELECT @String = SUBSTRING([Flat File Source Error Output Column],2,CHARINDEX(',',[Flat File Source Error Output Column])-6)

and it works :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: The Trim functions can be misleading, they will not remove new lines

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess it's because you're imported string has a non-visible character at the end of the string that doesn't allow it to convert.  Your variable is char(11) but the string '12/18/2009' is only 10 characters long so that leaves room for 1 more character at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @CheckString potentially has a newline character at the beginning.